# Function not firing when object's z rotation exceeds a limit

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

So, I'm trying to make a game where the cannon follows the mouse. However, I do not want it to follow it all the way down into the ground, so I want it to stop before it goes there. I tried using a clamp method, but it did not work. I tried a different approach. Here's my code:`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CannonPoint : MonoBehaviour {
   public GameObject cannon;
   public float rotateSpeed = 5;

   public float minAngle = -60;
   public float maxAngle = 60;

  void FixedUpdate(){
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, mousePos - transform.position);
  }
  void Update(){
    if (transform.rotation.z > 71.759f) {
        Debug.Log ("not working");
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, 71.759f);
    }
    if (transform.rotation.z < -71.759f) {
        Debug.Log ("not working");
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, -71.759f);
    }
  }
}`
```

When I do this, the function does not fire. In the update, the inspector tells me that the rotation is in fact greater than 71.759, but the Debug.Log does not fire Why does this happen! I'm getting very confused. Thanks!

(Just so you know my main goal is to keep the cannon pointing from going underneath the ground.)

Comment: Did you found what you were looking for?

Comment: @Ankit No, I put my new code under your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are working with rotation in Unity, It's kinda confusing at first newcomers before you fully understand it.

See When you get value from **`transform.rotation`** it will return an object of **`Quaternion`** in. Unity **`Quaternion`**'s axis value goes from zero(**0**) to One(**1**).
In your case, there is no chance for your condition to be true or **z** value to reach 71.759.

Instead, I suggest you use **`transform.eulerAngles.z`** to check the rotation of your object.

**Update:** for you where something follows the position of mouse pointer I've prepared some code for you.

```
Vector3 v = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    v = v - t.position;
    a = Mathf.Atan2(v.y, v.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
    Vector3 angles = t.eulerAngles;
    angles.z = Mathf.Clamp(a, -70f, 70f);
    t.eulerAngles = angles;
```

This is all you need its tested as well.
and more info about aim to the mouse pointer position check out this video [TOP DOWN SHOOTING in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNLVOjbrQj4&t=576s)

Comment: `if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 71.759f) {
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, 71.759f);
}
if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < -71.759f) {
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, -71.759f);
}`

Comment: I think you should use transform.eulerAngle.x and transformeulerAngle.y instead.

Comment: where should I put these?

Comment: this is my new code, still doesn't work D: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 71.759f);`